# Hibernate: Choose List instead Set

Tags: java, list, hibernate, set

I'm using Hibernate to convert DB to Entity and DAO Classes.
Hibernate chooses Set type automatically, but I need List type. 
How can I change Hibernate settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must use createCriteria method of session and keep in list of your object, like this:

```
List<YourDAO> list = getSession().createCriteria(YourDAO.class).list();
```

or createQuery method and after use .list for get data:

```
Query q = getSession().createQuery("select o from yourDAO o");
List<YourDao> list = q.list();
```

This will give you all the records of your entity in DB.

Comment: I'm generating Enities from DB schema. Hibernarte chooses Set(HashSet type) automatically. I want to use List type instead Set type.
`private Set orders` -> `private List orders`